# Remove unknown css element from image, only in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

When viewing my page with IE, I get these unknown CSS elements for images that I cannot seem to remove.  **The odd 3d style image inset type thing.**  I **do not** have this problem in Chrome.  This issue is not site breaking, but I would like resolve this.

[http://www.cashgrainbids.com/ie_issue.png http://www.cashgrainbids.com/ie_issue.png](http://www.cashgrainbids.com/ie_issue.png)

HTML

```
 <img src="" id="areaMappingToggle" class="toggleImageClose" alt=""/>
```

CSS

```
 .toggleImageOpen
    {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline;
    background: url(../Images/Basis/arrow_open.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .toggleImageOpen:hover
    {
    background-position: 0px -12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .toggleImageClose
    {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline;
    background: url(../Images/Basis/arrow_close.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .toggleImageClose:hover
    {
    background-position: 0px -12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

I have tried every CSS change i can think of and searched online for the issue, but cannot find anything similar.  Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the border? `border: 0`

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or the site itself?

Comment: @jackJoe, I have tried border: 0 as well as many other border options and combinations. Image is not within an <a>, it is within a table->thead->th, any styling on the table has been removed and the issue persists.

Comment: I assume that image is within a `<a>`? have you tried removing that `a`s border?

Comment: Also, try not using the img tag to show the image. Use a div tag, because you're providing the actual image as CSS background.

Comment: @strelok, that did it, with a <div> instead of <img>, it removed the effect.  I'm surprised there isn't a CSS property to manipulate to remove it as well.  Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE displays this border when it can't load an image. Remove the background image from your style and put the path in the src attribute of the img element or change the `img` element to a `<div>` or `<span>`

Comment: I checked this answer because it was provided and it allows the question to be closed, note must be given to Strelok, who posted comment first that solved the issue.  ZippyV thanks for your help as well!